# Merging two tables in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I just need to merge two tables (to player_new) without conflict.

In table 1 (player_new) I have 65,000 records.
In table 2 (player_old) I have 47,500 records.

Table structure for both are:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for player_new
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `player_new`;
CREATE TABLE `player_new` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varbinary(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NONAME'
  ........................
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for player_old
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `player_old`;
CREATE TABLE `player_old` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varbinary(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NONAME'
  ........................
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There some names are duplicated and I just need give same names to %s_x (in player_new table), so player can change his name later.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try restructuring your table as suggested by @echo_me, but still what you want can be achieved by merging both the table data to a separate table and then renaming that new table to `player_new` as below. See a demo fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c22d7e/2)

```
create table merged_player (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varbinary(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NONAME'
);

insert into merged_player(account_id,name)
select account_id,name from player_new
union
select account_id,name from player_old;

drop table player_new;

rename table merged_player to player_new;
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use just one table like that

```
CREATE TABLE `player` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Newname` varbinary(24)  DEFAULT 'NONAME',
`Oldname` varbinary(24)  DEFAULT 'NONAME'
 ......
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

then when you insert new name just update Newname column. and let Oldname

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned both tables are having same table description . we can use some logic like

```
insert into table1
select * from table2
```

I mean for your context its simply

```
insert into player_new
select * from player_old
```

I have done small try , just look at the image.

[image]

Comment: Though a good suggestion but you can't directly insert like that cause `id` is a auto increment column.